# Extract people names from unstructured yearbooks text

Tags: algorithm, nlp, text-mining, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I have many scanned pages of USA school yearbooks with people portraits and names. All texts from the pages are OCR'ed and collected in several versions per each page:

1. Unstructured text file. [Example](http://textuploader.com/d4ov1)
2. Xml with coordinates of every sentence. [Example](http://textuploader.com/d4ov4)
3. Xml with coordinates of every single letter. [Example](https://file.io/DKgMlq)

[image: Sample yearbooks page]

The goal is to determine which text strings represents person name and correlate it with portraits. The problem is that every single yearbook is unique and every single page is also could be unique, so no common pattern could be applied (but probably some number of common patterns). Another problem is that the pages contains many other texts besides names and collection is huge.

Example above has names written in capital letters, so they can be easily identified, but it's not the common case.

Another example:

[image: Sample yearbooks page]
[Text](http://textuploader.com/d4on5) / [XML1](http://textuploader.com/d4on1) / [XML2](https://file.io/1fkzmR)

Here is [few more examples](https://file.io/UN0g6B)

I'm thinking on few directions:

1. Use dictionary of US names to build an index and search every
   single word from the page within this index to find possible names.
2. Use Name-Entiry Recognition. I tried `opennlp` Java library, but
   it was working only for names that started with capital letter.
   Maybe other libraries will work.
3. Train some neural network. Can results of this be better than
   first two options?

Could you suggest which algorithms could help to solve this problem?

Comment: (1) That's very broad! (2) In the first example, you can use face-detection followed by gender-identification which makes it much easier to reason about which name maps to which image (mostly row-major vs. column-major ordering). (3) In the second example, i can't map those names to images. Your algorithm needs to be much more powerful than i am in this case. **Edit:** on second sight, i can. So my reasoning is again solely based on the approach mentioned in (2). (4) Sidenote: are you allowed to post these? If those are real yearbooks, my country probably would disallow posting these here.

Comment: The main goal right now is to extract names from the text (first name and surname) Correlation to portraits seems more easy task.

Comment: So how do you map these in example 2? That's pretty much a 50/50 (or worse) guessing.

Comment: In this case it could be guessing, this kind of pages are rare. But still, need to extract names - it's a main goal.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed NER would be helpfull, using existing software is ok but I'd suggest, for such a subdomain (person names), to implement an ad-hoc algorithm using lists of possible firstnames / lastnames as features and standard clues (e.g. uppercase letters, Miss / Mr.).

To associate names with portraits using male / female features would certainly be a good idea.

Implementing both separately (name recognition / portrait matching) as ambiguous processes would be nice: it will allow to select, among likely hypothesis, those that maximises other criterion : nb of names vs nb of portraits, regularity of layout to associate names with portraits, etc.

Mostly commonsense but I hope it helps a little bit!

PS don't forget situations where it is impossible to associate names with portrait, for instance by using a likelihood threshold (at first sight it seems to be the case with your last picture?)

Answer (score 0):

It may sound silly, but my first idea: FIRSTNAME LASTNAME seem to be uppercase

On a more serious note: Miss Xxx Yyy or Mr Xxx Yyy as regular expression (words, incl. 'woods' starting with upper case),  - or make a distinct list of all words, filter out those that come from a dictionary (e.g. sentiments from R package tidytext) and check the rest, combine bespoke two methods.

I think exploring data this way will yield lots of insights you need before going for nnet

Comment: The problem that names not always written in capital letters. Besides, more texts on the page can be written in same way that names, also in capital letters. Sometimes name could be in regular case, but school team or something else - in capital letters. And having Mr Miss prefixes is not common case.